# How to implement an attention layer as described in this paper with tensorflow-keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

[image]

This is the overall architecture, I did not understand the attention layer as described in the other image (fragment of the paper which describe the attention layer implementation).
In other words how do I implement the formula H^(t,l) = ....   ?

I was thinking to build a custom Lambda layer which does the job, but i really don't know how to write the custom lambda function.

[image]